# unable to Deserializ the form data Error !! Invalid JSON Primitive

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to Deserialized my JASON Serialized FormData

Please review my code

```html
///here its my JSON  

$("#btn_pro_spc").click(function () {
  var formdata = $("#Product_spec_from").serialize();
  $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("UpdateProductSpecification", "LC_LabChecking")',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { formdata : formdata },
               datatype:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                                  }
            });
});
```

```html
///here it controller


 public JsonResult UpdateProductSpecification(string formdata)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            LabCheckingModel LCModel = jss.Deserialize<LabCheckingModel>(formdata);


            return Json(jss);
        }
```

I Am getting serialized data perfectly but unable to Deserialized :(
Invalid JSON Primitive

Comment: Just make the parameter of you method your model - `public JsonResult UpdateProductSpecification(LabCheckingModel formdata)` - it will be automatically

Comment: And it just needs to be `data: $("#Product_spec_from").serialize(),` or else you need to add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: The Desrialize method expect string input not Model... LabCheckingModel LCModel = jss.Deserialize<LabCheckingModel>(formdata);

Comment: You don't need any of this. The `DefaultModelBinder` does all this automatically and will bind direct to your model

Comment: Not working it shows model values NULL now..not binding

Comment: Did you make the changes in my second comment

Comment: yes i made them $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("UpdateProductSpecification", "LC_LabChecking")',
               type: 'POST',
               data: $("#Product_spec_froml").serialize(),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               datatype:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   
                }

            });

Comment: If you have used `data: $("#Product_spec_froml").serialize(),`, then remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: OO thanx alot its working...values are binding i removed content type its working fine now ..cheers !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use use `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize your model. The `DefaultModelBinder` will do all this for you.  Change the script to

```
$("#btn_pro_spc").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateProductSpecification", "LC_LabChecking")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#Product_spec_from").serialize(), // change this
    datatype:'json',
    success: function (data) {
    }
  });
});
```

and change the controller method to

```
public JsonResult UpdateProductSpecification(LabCheckingModel model)
{
  // the value of model will be correctly bound
  return return Json(??);
}
```

Side note: not sure what you are trying to return (currently its an instance of `JavaScriptSerializer` which does not make sense)